# Merging dataframes on one column while replacing values with another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
mapping = pd.DataFrame({'idx': ['a','b','c'], 'val': [1, 2, 3]})
obs = pd.DataFrame({'obs': ['a','c','a','a','b','d']})
```

I would like for all observations in `obs`, that are present in `mapping`s `idx` column, to get the value of `mapping`s `val` column. If the value does not exist in `mapping`s `idx` column, it should be discarded.

That is, I would like to end up with the following dataframe:

```
obs_mapped = pd.DataFrame({'obs': [1,3,1,1,2]})
```

Is there a handy way to do this with pandas?

Comment: `obs.merge(mapping.rename(columns={'idx': 'obs'}))[['val']]`

Comment: @mozway - For me ouput is like `[1,1,1,3,2]`, for you working correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
out = (obs.assign(obs = obs['obs'].map(mapping.set_index('idx')['val']))
          .dropna(subset=['obs'])
          .astype(mapping.val.dtype))
print (out)
   obs
0    1
1    3
2    1
3    1
4    2
```

Or if use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) need multiple `rename` with sorting by original indices converted to column:

```
out = (obs.rename(columns={'obs':'idx'}).reset_index()
          .merge(mapping)
          .rename(columns={'val':'obs'})
          .sort_values('index', ignore_index=True)[['obs']])
print (out)
   obs
0    1
1    3
2    1
3    1
4    2
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)/[`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), however if you want to ensure having the values in order and mapping only the existing values, then pre-filter with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) before [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
out = (obs.loc[obs['obs'].isin(mapping['idx']), 'obs']
          .map(mapping.set_index('idx')['val'])
          .to_frame()
       )
```

Output:

```
   obs
0    1
1    3
2    1
3    1
4    2
```